# Inserting data into hive S3 external table using INSERT INTO SELECT overwrites file

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I have an external table (`tbl_external`) pointing to an S3 location.

I am trying to insert data into the external table using another table (`tbl_test`) which is not an external table.

```
insert into tbl_external select * from tbl_test;
```

But Hive is always generating a file with same file name (`000000_0`) when I run the above insert statement. As a result, the file is getting overwritten and the S3 location will always have a single file instead of multiple files when I run the insert statements multiple times.

How can I make Hive generate different file names? (eg `000000_0_copy_1`, `000000_0_copy_2`, etc)

We don't have this problem in our Dev environment, we are facing the problem only in Prod.

- Dev Hive version is `1.2.1.2.3.6.0-3796`
- Prod Hive version is `1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37`

Comment: Are you using Amazon EMR or your own installation of Hadoop on EC2?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am using my own installation of Hadoop on EC2 instances